# Compiling C++ ImpulseEngine to JavaScript with Emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, opengl, webgl, emscripten

Using Emscripten, I've been trying to compile the [ImpulseEngine project by Randy Gaul (C++)](https://github.com/RandyGaul/ImpulseEngine) to a JavaScript program. Once I got Emscripten running, I followed the tutorial described [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html). I followed all of the steps: Linking the .cpp files into the .bc files, then compiling those into a .js.

Here's a list of the commands I ran:

.cpp -> .bc:

```
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/main.cpp -o main.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Scene.cpp -o Scene.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Render.cpp -o Render.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Precompiled.cpp -o Precompiled.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Manifold.cpp -o Manifold.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Collision.cpp -o Collision.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Clock.cpp -o Clock.bc
emcc ImpulseEngine-master/Body.cpp -o Body.bc
```

.bc -> .js

```
emcc main.bc Scene.bc Render.bc Precompiled.bc Manifold.bc Collision.bc Clock.bc Body.bc -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -o github/khanfusiion3.github.io/index.html
```

Note the `-s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1` option: That's for enabling the OpenGL features. Granted, when I ran the command, I still received a few warnings about unresolved symbols, as seen here:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: glPointSize
warning: unresolved symbol: glRasterPos2i
warning: unresolved symbol: glutBitmapCharacter
warning: unresolved symbol: glutBitmap9By15
```

Theoretically, the program will fail now regardless of what happens next, but I tried anyways. It immediately threw an error and exited. Here is a list of every error logged to the console:

```
WARNING: using emscripten GL emulation. This is a collection of limited workarounds, do not expect it to work.Module.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249 WARNING: using emscripten GL emulation unsafe opts. If weirdness happens, try -s GL_UNSAFE_OPTS=0Module.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249 pre-main prep time: 12 msModule.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249 WARNING: using emscripten GL immediate mode emulation. This is very limited in what it supportsModule.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249 missing function: glRasterPos2iModule.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1237 -1
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249 -1Module.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249 warning: build with  -s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1  to link in libcxxabi demanglingModule.printErr @ khanfusiion3.github.io/:1249
/index.js:1879 Uncaught abort(-1) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:1060:13)
    at stackTrace (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:1077:22)
    at abort (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:25065:44)
    at _glRasterPos2i (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:8051:58)
    at __Z12RenderStringiiPKc (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:13374:2)
    at Array.__Z11PhysicsLoopv (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:9462:2)
    at dynCall_v (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:24605:30)
    at Object.Runtime.dynCall (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:331:39)
    at http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:8107:21
    at Object.Browser.mainLoop.runIter (http://khanfusiion3.github.io/index.js:1873:13)
```

I also tried running it with the `-s DEMANGLE_SUPPORT=1` option but the other errors didn't stop, so it still failed.

Any help on what's causing the errors and how to fix them?

Comment: It looks like the symbols glPointSize, glRasterPos2i, glutBitmapCharacter, and glutBitmap9By15 were unresolved. As you already saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImpulseEngine is using OpenGL, which is a very complex API programs use to access graphics hardware through dedicated drivers.  The drivers and the associated API are unavailable within the browser environment emscripten targets; you're not going to get it to work.

If you could find a similar library that targets SDL--a commonly-used library which provides a higher-level encapsulation of graphics APIs--you might port it to emscripten, since emscripten claims to support SDL.  In this case emscripten would be providing the lower-level implementation of the SDL graphics calls, translating them to the appropriate javascript-compatible APIs.

Comment: Alright, so if I were to edit ImpulseEngine itself, all I would need to do is change the rendering bits, correct?

Comment: @Raiden That's correct -- you could try porting it to SDL.

Comment: Alright, shouldn't be too hard. After all, it is just basic circles and lines.

Comment: If you want to use the old deprecated immediate mode OpenGL API you could try [regal](https://github.com/p3/regal)